# Can't see values in console.log() in nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an js file which includes an array! The js file is like this one

```
export const appointments = [
{
  "taskID": 9018929,
  "resource_ID": 1,
  "title": "KNDL Thatcham",
  "description": "<Non-Selected>\r\n10:00 - 18:00",
  "startTime": "2018-12-28T00:00:00",
  "endTime": "2018-12-28T23:59:00",
  "statusColour": "#DFDFDF",
  "clientColour": "#FFFDD7"
}]
```

I have imported this js files in service.ts. And this appointments.js does not show in the console.log.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { appointments } from '../appointments';
        import { Color } from "tns-core-modules/color";
        // >> angular-calendar-require
        import { CalendarEvent } from 'nativescript-ui-calendar';


        @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
        })


    export class CalendarService {

      constructor() { 
      //var a="test test etsdhsakdsakd dsddssdsd";
      console.log(appointments);
    }
```

This is the component where I am importing the service.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { CalendarService } from "./service/calendar.service";
import { RadCalendar, CalendarEvent, CalendarSelectionEventData } from "nativescript-ui-calendar";
@Component({
  selector: 'ns-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css'],
  moduleId: module.id,
  providers: [CalendarService]
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `CalendarService()` is being instantiated? What happens if you move `console.log(appointments);` outside of the class definition (ie, directly after the `import`)?

Comment: @DacreDenny I had imported the service.ts in another component! I will let you know if it works after the import part! Check the code again, I have added the component part where I imported the service.ts

Comment: You have just mentioned the `providers`. I don't think an instance of `CalendarService` may be created until you inject it in the component's constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a private calendarService parameter of type CalendarService to the constructor.

When Angular creates a CalendarComponent , the [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) system sets the calendarService parameter to the singleton instance of CalendarService .

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(calendarService : CalendarService ) {}

}

Comment: like this one? `constructor(private _calendarApiService: calendarApiService) {
    
   }`

Comment: Still I do not get the console.log() in the terminal! I checked tns doctor! All are okay! But still it is not showing!

Comment: Try to have console.log inside constructor to make sure that caldendarComponent is getting initiated

Comment: I tried. But It does not show up! This is the message I find in the terminal `Successfully synced application org.nativescript.UnityMobile on device LGAS992174f3745.
Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
Preparing project...
Project successfully prepared (Android)
Successfully transferred api.service.js on device LGAS992174f3745.
Restarting application on device LGAS992174f3745...
device: LGAS992174f3745 debug port: 40000

Comment: that means your calendarcomponent is not getting called. Make sure you have calendarcomponent in declartion of app.modules.ts

Comment: I had already done it still it fails to show! ` declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ItemsComponent,
        ItemDetailComponent,
        CalendarComponent,
        ChatComponent,
        ProfileComponent,
        TimeAgoPipe
    ],`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189038/discussion-between-narendra-mongiya-and-nabid).